# Why WEP wifi network is not found by SK17i?

Tags: wi-fi, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I cannot to connect to a school wifi network. When I go to wi-fi settings the phone shows all the unencrypted networks and the WPA encrypted networks. But this network is encrypted with WEP.
Any clue where's the problem?

All the issues I googled are that the network is visible, but the connection fails. In my case the network is NOT visible.
From my PC the connection to that network works fine.
I can NOT access the configuration of the router. (E.g.: Change the encryption to WPA.)

My phone is Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro (SK17i). Android version 2.3.4.

Comment: Is the wifi network running in a frequency band that the phone doesn't support, perhaps (like a 5GHz band)?

Comment: Or maybe in different channel like 14?

Comment: Right now I checked: Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

Comment: Any progress made? It's more than a year ago meanwhile, and no updates on this issue...

Comment: Not really. I just got Internet from another source.